# Conflict resolution between in-class member initializer and initialization list

Tags: c++, c++11

Let me precede the question with the following code:

```
struct A
{
  explicit A(int i):a_{i} {}

  int a_
};

struct B
{
  B():mya_{5} {} // Initialize mya_ (again?)

  A mya_{7}; // Initialize mya_
};
```

In `struct B` we have a conflict between the in-class initializer for `mya_` and `mya_` being initialized in `B`'s constructor's initializer list. How is this resolved per the C++ standard and what should the final value of `mya_.a_` be when `B`'s construction is complete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initialization list wins. The in-place initialization would win if you had another constructor that does not initialize the member.

For example,

```
struct B
{
  B():mya_{5} {}
  B(int) {}
  A mya_{7};
};

int main
{
  B b0;    // b.mya_.a_ is 5
  B b(42); // b.mya_.a_ is 7
}
```

From **12.6.2 Initializing bases and members [class.base.init]**

> If a given non-static data member has both a
>   brace-or-equal-initializer and a mem-initializer, the initialization
>   specified by the mem-initializer is performed, and the non-static data
>   member’s brace-or-equal-initializer is ignored. [ Example: Given

```
struct A {
int i = /∗ some integer expression with side effects ∗/ ;
A(int arg) : i(arg) { }
// ...
};
```

> the A(int) constructor will simply initialize i to the value of arg,
>   and the side effects in i’s brace-or-equal- initializer will not take
>   place. — end example ]